# How to stack nearrow and searrow on top of one another?

Tags: math-mode

I want to transcribe this equation:

[image]

I tried to use both `\stackrel` and `\overset` to get the stacked arrows. But the output looks weird, with one arrrow significantly smaller than the other:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\begin{document} 

\begin{align*}
&\qquad (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\text{log}N}, l + 1) \\
(b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\text{log}N}, l + 1) \stackrel{\nearrow}{\searrow} & \\
&\qquad (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\text{log}N}, l + 1) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you measure the difference? Visually, to my untrained eyes, it really doesn't look too bad. The lower one I guess is a little bit longer, but they are nice looking arrows.

Comment: @AFeldman `\stackrel` puts the first argument in *scriptstyle* above the second argument, i.e. the upper arrow is actually shorter and the results looks unbalanced.

Comment: Do *not* use `\text{log}`.  I see that so often and it is just wrong!  There is a huge number of predefined operators such as `\log` and even if your operator does not exist, e.g. `\arsinh`, then you'd use `\operatorname{arsinh}` or if you want to use it several times declare it in the preamble using `\DeclareMathOperator\arsinh{arsinh}`.

Comment: @Henri Menke Thanks for the tip. I will go back and fix that. I am a Latex noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be very easily done with a `\stackanchor`, with the optional argument providing the desired separation gap (shown as 8pt on the arrows and 20pt on the subsequent expressions)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath

\begin{document}
\[
(b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\text{log}N}, l + 1)
~\stackanchor[8pt]{\nearrow}{\searrow}~
\stackanchor[20pt]{(b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\text{log}N}, l + 1)}
  {(b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\text{log}N}, l + 1) }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one for the simplicity. Thanks everyone for your help. Sorry I can't accept every answer, as most the proprosed solutions produced the right output.

Answer (score 7):

Use `array`. I set the intercolumn space to zero, but surround `\nearrow` and `\searrow` with empty subformulas, so the “relation space” is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{rcl}
&& (b_1,b_2, \dots, b_{l + 1}, \dots, b_{\log N}, l + 1) \\
& {}\nearrow{} \\
(b_1,b_2, \dots, b_{l + 1}, \dots, b_{\log N}, l + 1) \\
& {}\searrow{} \\
&&(b_1,b_2, \dots, \overline{b_{l + 1}}, \dots, b_{\log N}, l + 1)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

borrowing an idea from henri menke, but rearranging the elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation*}
(b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1)
\mkern 9mu \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\nearrow}{\searrow}
 \begin{aligned}
  & \; (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1)
  \\[.75\baselineskip]
  & \; (b_1,b_2, \dots \overline{b_{l + 1}}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1) 
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\genfrac`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align*}
&\; (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1) \\
(b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1)
\; \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\nearrow}{\searrow} & \\
&\; (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or use `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzcd}
  & (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1) \\
  (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1) \ar[ru] \ar[rd] & \\
  & (b_1,b_2, \dots b_{l + 1}, \dots b_{\log N}, l + 1) \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't this look better of the arrows was placed at the end of the first node? Doable using `\ar[ru,start anchor={[yshift=2pt]east},end anchor=south west] 
  \ar[rd,start anchor={[yshift=-2pt]east},end anchor=north west]`

Comment: @daleif Yes, it would, but then the code would no longer be so minimal.  It also remains questionable whether this arrow notation is well chosen.

Comment: Sure, if a diagram structure was needed I might even have used `|-` lines instead

Comment: And I would definitely add some sort of `bend left` or `bend right` which might give mor naturality (and beauty) to the “diagram”.